# React Native. Single instance of React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, singleton

I have serious problem, but I have no idea how can I resolve it.

Let's say that I have to prepare a view, where are placed two twin movie players. I prepared simple component:

```
interface Props {
    episode: Episode;
}
interface State {
    paused: boolean;
}
export class VideoPlayer extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      paused: true,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() => {
          this.setState({paused: !this.state.paused});
        }}
      >
        <Video
          source={{ uri: episode.videoUrl }}
          paused={paused} />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>)
  }
}
```

OK, Now in render function in my ScreenComponent I'm trying add two twin VideoPlayer components, but with the same reference, like this:

```
render() {
  const videoPlayer = (<VideoPlayer episode={this.props.firstEpisode} />)
  <View>
   {videoPlayer}
   {videoPlayer}
  </View>
}
```

It's works. On my screen I can see two video players playing the same episode, but I have problem! I want them to play simultaneously when clicking on one of them. Now, they both operate separately, despite pointing to the same reference

---

Is there any way to create something like **Singleton component** in react native? How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, can you try having `VideoPlayer` accept a state variable from the parent to determine whether it is "playing" or not? So when you press on either videoplayer it fires a callback to the parent that changes the state to true/false and passes that back into both children simultaneously?

So essentially you have this:

```
render() {
  const videoPlayer = (<VideoPlayer episode={this.props.firstEpisode} isPlaying={this.state.isVideoPlaying} />)
  <View>
   {videoPlayer}
   {videoPlayer}
  </View>
}
```

And `VideoPlayer` would no longer have its own state, just props.